# Ignoring didReceiveMemoryWarning in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, objective-c++, didreceivememorywarning

According to Apple docs if an app ignores a memory warning, the system could force freeing the dirty memory, if it needs some. At the same time in some cases manual freeing the data in responce to the memory warning and later restoring it is not acceptable for the performance reason. So is it possible to know if certain class instance members were actually forcedly cleared? Are they assigned `nil`? And what about the pointers to C++ objects being the members of Obj-C objects?

Comment: Where did you read that the OS forces freeing dirty memory?

Comment: Actually I heard about it in WWDC 2012 Session 242 IOS app performance - memory video

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it works. The OS will free the memory by quitting your app. The OS can not go in and randomly delete objects, because it has no way of understanding which objects would be safe to clear and which ones wouldn't.

IIRC the only thing it sometimes does is unload a few view controllers' views (but not the actual controller object) that are stacked e.g. in a navigation controller and not currently visible. It can do that because it knows how to load these views and what ivars they are referenced by (because you told it via IBOutlet etc.), so it can and will actually NIL those.

**Update:** There are also some cache classes these days that will evict their objects on receiving a memory warning, but you would have to explicitly use those classes for your objects to be released.